# Why does matlab close on execution of this code and how can I trace what is wrong?

Tags: debugging, matlab

I'm executing Dimension Reduction algo from this tool box [DR toolbox](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/19j49/Matlab_Toolbox_for_Dimensionality_Reduction.html). I'm executing Linear Discriminant Analysis code on this data set [Gisette](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Gisette). Executing on train_data and train_labels. When I execute the code runs but after some time matlab shuts down by itself. Not able to figure why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracing MATLAB crashes is notoriously difficult (I used to work there doing exactly that for customers).

Even if there's a JAVA dump, or a seg-fault listing, there's not really a whole lot you can do to figure out what line this is on without going through line-by-line with the MATLAB de-bugger.  And if the problem is random, or memory based, you might never track it down.

That's the bad news.  The good news is that 95% of crashes are due to 3rd party MEX files and associated memory leaks.  I'd guess in the dim-reduction toolbox is a MEX file, and that is what's crashing.  And it's deterministic.  If that's the case, you can dbstop and dbstep through the code to figure out which line MATLAB disappears on, then report that to the toolbox developers. Or start to edit the MEX file's C-code.

Here's information on debugging in case you didn't already know:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html;jsessionid=b3d5f42e047aacb596868b7a5961

If that doesn't work, try another toolbox.

My friends and I wrote one that's free:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/linkexchange/links/2947-pattern-recognition-toolbox